# Google OAuth2 - Installed Application - Always seeing a consent screen

Tags: google-oauth

I am trying to setup a sign in form inside a C# application. One of the options to sign in is via Google. For this, I am using the Oauth2 doc for Installed applications: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp.

Everything appears to work as expected but for the **Consent Screen**. I am being shown the Consent Screen for every request for the authorization code. Is that expected for an Installed Application? I am using the following parameters:

> redirect_uri = urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
>
> response_type = code

I have tried to set *approval_prompt* to *auto* and tried combinations of *access_type* to *offline* and *online*, but still that does not help.

Note that similar experiments with a "Web application" (using different client id) works fine where I see the Consent Screen only once.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you keeping the refresh token and re-presenting that? "Offline" shouldn't affect this - that's to do with allowing the app to work when the user is not logged in and present. Shouldn't affect sign in.

Comment: I try to preserve the refresh token for as long as I can, and am able to use it for a long time. But, to support multiple users, I sometimes delete the refresh token of a particular user but would like to re-acquire the same, without going through the consent screen.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? If you delete the refresh token for a user, then you'd expect that consent needs to be given again - you're not presenting an authentication that what you want to do, is permitted. So consent should be sought. Why do you think it shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

For installed applications, the idea is that you'll get a code and convert that to a refresh token and store the refresh token. A user shouldn't need to sign in again and again. Is the user signing out of the app or you are deleting the token after a certain time?

The reason the behavior is different on the web is because we decided to give a "code" back without an approval (in case of application was already approved by the user) but this code can not be used to convert to a refresh token. We did this because users do end up signing out of the web applications due to various reasons (cookies go away) and developers request a "code" without knowing whether a user has already approved or not.

Comment: Correct. The user is "signing out" from the app, and then I delete the refresh token.

So, for installed applications, is the user forced to go through the consent screen every time?

Comment: @user3933772 - yes, because they've given their consent, and then you've deleted it (the refresh token). So long as you keep telling the service that you don't have consent, you'll need to seek it again. Logout != withdrawal of consent.

Comment: I guess that's my confusion because the same sequence for a "web application" does not show the consent screen every time I am trying to am trying to get the "refresh token".